# Rails inherit class shared attributes on build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

assuming i have two models human and male, they both have similar attributes but not all the attributes, for example:

```
class Human < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :males
  
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, presence: true
  validates :date_of_birth, presence: true
  validates :identity, presence: true
end


class Male < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :human
  
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :age, presence: true
end
```

now what i want to do is when i use `human.males.build` i want the new male instance to inherit the shared attributes like `name` and `age`
instead of using this behavior `human.males.build({attributes})`

Comment: So `males` do not have a `date_of_birth` nor an `identity`? It is certainly just me, but to me your example doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I’m also unclear on the design—an actual example might be required to understand. Right now it looks like the design is off.

Comment: This sounds like you're grasping at [Delegated types](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/DelegatedType.html).

Comment: The weird thing about this question is that `Male` and `Human` are not connected in any way via inheritance. Did you try to use STI (single table inheritance) in Rails?

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking of overwriting the `initialize` (alias of `build`) method of `Male` model which will do the trick:

```
def initialize(attributes = {}, &block)
  super(attributes, &block)
  self.name = human.name unless attributes[:name].present?
  self.age = human.age unless attributes[:age].present?
end
```

But honestly, I don't think this is a safe and generic way for the problem.

Comment: `initialize` is key hook of the Ruby Language. `build` is an alias for `new` in ActiveRecord that is just around for silly legacy reasons.